# Promise approach in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have attempted to create a lazy loading solution for my posts, see below:

```
$scope.loadMore = function() {

  if(hasRunBefore===0){
      page+=1;
  }

  if($scope.postsCount > $scope.posts.length){
      $http.get('/api/posts', {params: { page: page, pageSize: 10 }})
      .then(function(res){
          var morePosts = res.data.posts;
          if(morePosts && morePosts.length > 0){
              loadData(morePosts);
              page+=1;
              hasRunBefore+=1;
          }
      });
      }
  };

};

  var loadData = function(posts){
      $scope.posts = $scope.posts.concat(posts);
  };
```

Some notes:

1. `$scope.postsCount` is grabbed by getting the length of the whole table in Mongo, say this is 50 in this case
2. `$scope.loadMore` is called whenever you reach the end of a page on the frontend (`infinite-scroll` is anyone's interested)
3. `$scope.loadMore` can be called multiple times as it is triggered when you reach the end of a page

The problem is - `loadData()` is the function that appends to the `$scope.posts`, so the `if($scope.postsCount > $scope.posts.length)` is always `true`

Question - I am new to the promise approach in Angular 1.6.x, i.e.: .then. How will I need to restructure this so that I wait for the `loadData()` to finish executing so that the `if($scope.postsCount > $scope.posts.length)` can be accurate?

Comment: Did not read through all your post, but I can see you are missing a `callback` function where `$scope.posts.length` could be evaluated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create loading property and set it as true during request. if load more function is called again check loading property

```
$scope.loading = false
$scope.loadMore = function() {

  if($scope.loading) return  // if page still loading dont allow
  $scope.loading = true


  if(hasRunBefore===0){
      page+=1;
  }


  if($scope.postsCount > $scope.posts.length){
      $http.get('/api/posts', {params: { page: page, pageSize: 10 }})
      .then(function(res){
          $scope.loading = false; // set loading as false after finish request
      });
      }
  };

};
```

Comment: Awesome answer. Simple yet beautiful. Thanks man. Wanna bang my head against the wall for not figuring it out :)